# Validate in array name Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

How to validate by Id laravel

now i use this in my controller. My problem is  In my html I've my input type text like this

```
<input type="text" name="quantity_box[]" class="form-control" autofocus="" />
<input type="text" name="quantity_box[1]" class="form-control" autofocus="" />
<input type="text" name="quantity_box[2]" class="form-control" autofocus="" />
```

well, as you see in my html It check only my first input if my `quantity_box[1]` is empty it will return error offset 1 , that's  not sure how to work this out

```
 $this->validate($request, [
        'id_p' => 'required',
        'id_c' => 'required',
        'quantity_box'=>'required',


    ]
```

Comment: For best practise I recommend to make use of `Form Request Validation` https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: thank you sir i'll check it out

Comment: I've put an example of this method as a second answer in case you or someone else might want to use it sometime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since you are validating the $request variable, you should be validating the input name.

If you are using Laravel 5.2+ , you can validate arrays like so.

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'quantity_box.*' => 'required',
     ]);
```

Comment: Is thier anyway to change validate by id ? be cause  It can be quantity_box[10]   I dnt know how many user will insert data

Comment: @test1321 Yes there is a method for that.

Comment: could you give me an example please @LarsMertens

Answer (score 1):

For best practise I recommend working with **Laravel's 5.5 Form Request Validation** [laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#form-request-validation)

Using this way you will keep your controller code as clean as possible.

---

**First let's make a Request to store our validation and authentication rules in**

```
php artisan make:request myQuantityBoxRequest
```

---

**myQuantiyBoxRequest.php**

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Auth;

class myQuantityBoxRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     * The user is always authorized here to make the request
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'quantity_box.*' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

**Controller Function Example**

```
use App\Http\Requests\myQuantityBoxRequest;

public function postQuantityBoxData(myQuantityBoxRequest $request){
     // Do something after validation here
}
```

There you go. If you make use of this function it will validate the input as if you're using `$this->validate()`

Comment: thank you sir this make me  more understand thank a lot sir